# Ito isometry for correlated Brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, isometry, quadratic-variation

This question [Ito isometry with two independent Brownian motions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163676/ito-isometry-with-two-independent-brownian-motions) asks for an Itô isometry for two independent Brownian motions $V_t,W_t:[0,T]\times\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$. It turns out that the independence of the Brownian motions renders the integrals independent and the expectation of the product becomes the product of expectations.

In the case where $W_t = V_t$, it follows from the classic Itô isometry that $$E\left[\left(\int_0^T X_t\,\mathrm dW_t\right)\left(\int_0^T Y_t\,\mathrm dW_t\right)\right] = \mathbb E\left[\int_0^T X_tY_t\,\mathrm d[W,W]_t\right],$$ where $[\cdot,\cdot]_t$ denotes the covariation.

In my case, however, I have $V_t\neq W_t$ and I can't assume that the Brownian motions are independent. In fact, I know that the correlation between $V_t$ and $W_t$ is equal to some constant $\rho$. Is there a result that gives me something like $$\mathbb E\left[\left(\int_0^T X_t\,\mathrm dV_t\right) \left(\int_0^T Y_t\,\mathrm dW_t\right)\right] \overset{?}{=} \mathbb E\left[\int_0^T X_tY_t\,\mathrm d[V,W]_t\right]?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M_t=\int_0^t X_s\,dV_s$ and $N_t=\int_0^t Y_s\,dW_s$, then by Problem 3.3.12 in [Karatzas and Shreve](https://books.google.com/books/about/Brownian_Motion_and_Stochastic_Calculus.html?id=uxnvAAAAMAAJ&source=kp_book_description),
$$
M_t N_t = \int_0^t M_s\,dN_s + \int_0^t N_s\,dM_s + [M, N]_t,
$$
giving
\begin{multline}
\left(\int_0^t X_s\,dV_s\right)\left(\int_0^t Y_s\,dW_s\right)\\
= \int_0^t M_s Y_s\,dW_s + \int_0^t N_s X_s\,dV_s
+ \int_0^t X_s Y_s\,d[V, W]_s.
\end{multline}
At Ito integral of the form $\int_0^t\theta_s\,dB_s$, where $B$ is a Brownian motion, is something called a local martingale. If, additionally, $E\int_0^t|\theta_s|^2\,ds<\infty$ for all $t$, then the Ito integral is a martingale. Martingales have the property that their expectation is constant over time. Since the expectation is zero at time $t=0$, it is always zero.

Thus, if $E\int_0^t|M_sY_s|^2\,ds<\infty$ and $E\int_0^t|N_sX_s|^2\,ds<\infty$, then the Ito integrals on the right-hand side of the above display are martingales. Taking expectations gives the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't follow though why the integrals become zero though once expectations are taken

Comment: @SydAmerikaner, I have edited the answer to address your question.

Answer (score 1):

Under the technical assumption that the two correlated Brownian motions are given as $W_t$ and
$$
V_t=\rho W_t+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\,W_t^\bot
$$
where $W_t^\bot$ is a BM uncorrelated with $W_t$ the formula is correct and follows easily
from linearity of the Ito integral in $dV_t$ and from $[V,W]_t=\rho\,t\,.$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I spent some time now thinking about your solution. If I get it correctly, the correlation matrix $R_t$ of the vector $(V_t,W_t)$ is decomposed by the Cholesky decomposition $R_t= L_tL_t^\top$, and the modified vector $L_t^{-1}(V_t,W_t)$ is analyzed instead. However, I don't think this result will help me as I would have to know $W_t^\top$ in order to implement the solution

Comment: We know now that there is Ito isometry under the technical but mild assumption that $W^\bot$ exists. To implement this (you mean Monte Carlo simulate?) pick independent RVs and combine them with the assumption formula to correlate them.